# ERD Issue: Gallery & Company Relationship is wrong

Tags: erd

*Quick Summary: I'm building an ERD diagram and got lost in connecting two tables.*

**Introduction:**
I'm building an ERD diagram for my project. Idea is pretty straight forward: I can type information about the company and it will be saved in the database. Later, I can see the list of submitted companies, as a list. As of now, I've information on the "paper", which I've implemented into my ERD diagram, so that later I can tell database, what exactly must be saved and where.

I have a primary table "Company_Info" which stores all the information about the company in the database. Using common sense (or not :)) I've created "Foreign Tables" that would store information about the company: "Gallery Images", "Opening_hours", etc. This way I believe, the database would more or less clear and readable by others.

[ERD Diagram with the Description of all relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0uoR.png)

**Problem Statement**
The idea was to create a simple gallery for the company, so that they can upload their Product-pictures. If it's possible I would like to talk about the relationship between the Gallery and the Company tables. The way I see it, I think it should be like this:

1. One company can have 0,1,2 or many images. (Gallery_Images Table)
2. Images must be assigned to only 1 company. (Company_Info Table)
3. The relationship is one mandatory to many optional. (Many images & one company)

**Question**: I think the relationship between the Gallery_Table and Company_Info table will not work. *Reason:* Wrong relationship. I'm confused about the connection between those two tables. 
I have made a connection via company PK & FK. This way, I think, the database would know what images belong to that specific company.

*Confusion is with gallery_id in Gallery_Images table. Shouldn't it be connected with the company_info table too?*

Answer (score 0):

Image(BLOB) is a repeating group in Gallery_Images.  This is not a problem if your purpose is to draw a diagram of an ER model.

If your purpose is to draw a diagram of a relational model, then the repeating group is a departure from First Normal Form.  Relational schemas that depart from 1NF are generally subject to terrible problems, both with regard to performance and with regard to data management itself.

I don't see the Gallery table in your diagram.  Did I miss something?